# Why does CMD substring not work when BAT called from SENDTO?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I wrote a BAT file to strip a leading '@' off a filename.  (Please don't ask why! ...why Windows, why CMD...) :)

Here's the BAT file:

```
IF EXIST "%~1" (

    FOR /F %%F IN ("%~1") DO (

        CD /D "%%~dpF"
        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
            ECHO.  Failed to CD to folder: %%~dpF
        ) ELSE (
            SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
            SET A=%%~nxF

            IF "%A:~0,1%"=="@" (

                ECHO.   RENAME "%A%" "%A:~1%"
                    RENAME "%A%" "%A:~1%"
                REM   RENAME "%%A%" "%%A:~1%"
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO.   File does not start with @:  %A%
            )
            ENDLOCAL
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO.    File not found:  %1
)

pause
```

When I run it from the command line in a DOS window, it seems to work:

```
18:54:04.97>dir /b *foo*
@foo.txt

18:54:07.97>test@ "%cd%\@foo.txt"

18:54:18.75>IF EXIST "C:\Users\me\lbin\@foo.txt" (FOR /F %F IN ("C:\Users\me\lbin\@foo.txt") DO (
CD /D "%~dpF"
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO.  Failed to CD to folder: %~dpF )  ELSE (
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
 SET A=%~nxF
 IF "@" == "@" (
ECHO.   RENAME "@foo.txt" "foo.txt"
 RENAME "@foo.txt" "foo.txt"
 REM   RENAME "%Afoo.txt"
)  ELSE (ECHO.   File does not start with @:  @foo.txt )
 ENDLOCAL
)
) )  ELSE (ECHO.    File not found:  "C:\Users\me\lbin\@foo.txt" )

18:54:18.77>(
CD /D "C:\Users\me\lbin\"
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO.  Failed to CD to folder: C:\Users\me\lbin\ )  ELSE (
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
 SET A=@foo.txt
 IF "@" == "@" (
ECHO.   RENAME "@foo.txt" "foo.txt"
 RENAME "@foo.txt" "foo.txt"
 REM   RENAME "%Afoo.txt"
)  ELSE (ECHO.   File does not start with @:  @foo.txt )
 ENDLOCAL
)
)
   RENAME "@foo.txt" "foo.txt"

18:54:18.80>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
18:54:20.74>
```

but when I run the BAT file from a shortcut in the SENDTO menu, the `substring` operation doesn't expand correctly - specifically, the "IF" doesn't expand right (`IF "%A:~0,1%"=="@" (`) - see?...

```
C:\Users\me\lbin>IF EXIST "C:\Users\me\lbin\@foo.txt" (FOR /F %F IN ("C:\Users\me\lbin\@foo.txt") D
O (
CD /D "%~dpF"
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO.  Failed to CD to folder: %~dpF )  ELSE (
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
 SET A=%~nxF
 IF "~0,1" == "@" (
ECHO.   RENAME "" "~1"
 RENAME "" "~1"
 REM   RENAME "%A~1"
)  ELSE (ECHO.   File does not start with @:   )
 ENDLOCAL
)
) )  ELSE (ECHO.    File not found:  C:\Users\me\lbin\@foo.txt )

C:\Users\me\lbin>(
CD /D "C:\Users\me\lbin\"
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO.  Failed to CD to folder: C:\Users\me\lbin\ )  ELSE (
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
 SET A=@foo.txt
 IF "~0,1" == "@" (
ECHO.   RENAME "" "~1"
 RENAME "" "~1"
 REM   RENAME "%A~1"
)  ELSE (ECHO.   File does not start with @:   )
 ENDLOCAL
)
)
   File does not start with @:

C:\Users\me\lbin>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

> [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) will cause variables to be expanded at
>   execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on
>   with the `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect
>   variables can be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to
>   the normal `%variable_name%`)

Hence, use `!A!`, `!A:~0,1!` and `!A:~1!` instead of `%A%`, `%A:~0,1%` and  `%A:~1%` respectively as follows:

```
        SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
        SET A=%%~nxF

        IF "!A:~0,1!"=="@" (

            ECHO.   RENAME "!A!" "!A:~1!"
                    RENAME "!A!" "!A:~1!"
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO.   File does not start with @:  !A!
        )
        ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: That's interesting, but is a suggested alternative implementation - and doesn't answer my question.  Why does _my_ implementation behave differently under "SendTo"?

Comment: Try `SET "A="` _before_ `test@ "%cd%\@foo.txt`; I am convinced that any difference will disappear.

Comment: I am very puzzled by the difference between running within `CMD.EXE` and and using `SendTo`. I can only guess that the environments are slightly different in some way. Maybe in interactive mode `ENABLEEXTENSIONS` is already set before the batch file is run? You could try moving the `SETLOCAL` to the head of the batch file, so as to exclude the effect of this.

Comment: @AFH moving `SETLOCAL` does not matter in this special case. The `%A%` evaluates in parsing time of _entire_ `IF EXIST "%~1" (...)` command doubtlessly. I'm pretty sure that running the `test@` script using `SendTo` is the same as `set "A=" & test@ "%cd%\@foo.txt"` from `cmd` CLI whilst the OP's case corresponds to `set "A=@foo.txt" & test@ "%cd%\@foo.txt"`.

Comment: @JosefZ - I created `test.bat` containing `cd` and `echo %1`, followed by `pause`; I then added a short-cut to it in the `SendTo` directory. When I send an arbitrary file to it, it shows the directory configured in the short-cut and the name of the selected file in `%1`; when I type `test FileName` in `cmd.exe` I get the current directory, with FileName in `%1`, as expected. I still don't see why the two cases parse differently.

Comment: @JosefZ - I have done more tests, this time using the questioner's batch file, and I found that both the interactive and the `SendTo` runs were identical. I then `SET A=ABC` and this time `test %CD%\@ttt` echoed `SET A=@ttt`, but the following line was echoed as `IF "A" == "@" (`, ie using the preset value, which was used on all the subsequent lines. So it seems that the difference was caused by a preset value of `A` in the interactive shell, showing that your analysis was absolutely correct. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @JosefZ - thanks for that clever insight - I'll test that.  If it's the root cause, I'll add another comment here & you can post it as an answer (i.e. pilot error). :)

Comment: @AFH I tried your suggestion.  Looks like you're right.  Please post this as an answer!

Comment: It was @JosefZ who identified the main problem, the need for delayed expansion, and I don't want to steal his thunder: perhaps he will incorporate my suggestions into his answer.